# Aspect ratio Media query for nexus 6

Tags: css, media-queries, aspect-ratio, nexus6

I have tried to find media query (aspect ratio Media query for nexus 6). but did't find anywhere. if anyone can help me in this matter then let me know.

i also tried to create ratio according to width/height by using this link (http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/) but it's not working for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asking a semi-related question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74915/reducing-media-queries seems to have used this:

```
/* Motorola Nexus 6 (portrait and landscape) */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1440px) and
(max-device-width : 2560px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 3.5) {
html {
    font-size: 200%;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have to find out the media query for nexus 6 according to device aspect ratio not by device width or device pixel ratio.
if you have any suggestion for this please suggest me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the aspect ratio, you just write the dimensions of it like this:
`@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 435/773) { }`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please understand the question first. what i want "@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 9/16)  { }" like that.

Comment: Okay, try this:
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 435/773) { }
Worked for me

Comment: Okay, I don't know what width and height your device has, but enter those as I did for my values and it should work, because the aspect ratio doesn't change if you have 10/20 or 1/2, in the end it's still the same ratio